# Have I put too much into my tooltip showing and hiding functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tonight I decided to revamp some code I wrote a few months ago. One part of that was to do with showing (and hiding) tooltips. The functions are called with:

```
jQuery(element).showTooltip('HTML');
jQuery(element).hideTooltip();
```

**The old code**

```
$.fn.showTooltip = function(text)
{
    /* Remove any existing tooltip. */
    $(this).removeTooltip();

    /* Generate a unique reference for the tooltip. */
    var ref = $(this).attr('name');

    /* Create the tooltip and add it after the element. */
    $tooltip = $('<span class="tooltip" data-ref="' + ref + '"></span>')
        .html(text)
        .css('display','none')
        .insertAfter($(this))
        .fadeIn(animationSpeed);
}

$.fn.removeTooltip = function()
{
    var ref = $(this).attr('name');

    /* Remove the tooltip. */
    $('span[data-ref="' + ref + '"]')
        .stop()
        .fadeOut(animationSpeed, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

This code did the trick, but the were a few occasions where a tooltip either wouldn't appear or disappear when required. Equally the animations were a bit off.

**The new *revamped* code**

```
$.fn.showTooltip = function(html) {
    var

        /* Create a unique reference to the element to be used in the
         * tooltip. */
        tooltipRef = $(this).attr('name'),

        /* Create a reference to any current tooltip for the element. */
        existingTooltip = $('[data-ref="' + tooltipRef + '"]'),

        /* Create a variable to be used to hold the new tooltip. */
        $tooltip

    ;   

    /* If existingTooltip doesn't match an existing object then create
     * the new tooltip object, asigning its HTML and hiding it before
     * inserting it after the element. */
    if(typeof existingTooltip != 'object'
        || typeof existingTooltip.length != 'number'
        || existingTooltip.length === 0)
        $tooltip = $('<span class="tooltip"></span>')
                    .attr('data-ref', tooltipRef)
                    .html(html)
                    .hide()
                    .insertAfter($(this));

    /* If existingTooltip is visible and that contains the same html
     * which is being passed in then there is no need to recreate. */
    else if(existingTooltip.is(':visible')
        && existingTooltip.html() === html)
        return;

    /* If existingTooltip is visible but does not contain the same html
     * then hide existingTooltip then set its HTML and set $tooltip as
     * existingTooltip. */
    else if(existingTooltip.is(':visible'))
    {
        $(this).hideTooltip();
        $tooltip = existingTooltip;
        $tooltip.queue(function() {
            $tooltip.html(html);
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }

    /* If existingTooltip isn't visible but contains the same HTML, set
     * $tooltip as existingTooltip. */
    else if(existingTooltip.html() === html)
        $tooltip = existingTooltip;

    /* If existingTooltip isn't visible and doesn't contain the same
     * HTML, set its HTML and set $tooltip as existingTooltip. */
    else if(existingTooltip.html() !== html)
    {
        existingTooltip.html(html);
        $tooltip = existingTooltip;
    }

    /* If none of the above applies then something has gone wrong. */
    else
        return;

    /* Ensure any current animation isn't occuring before displaying
     * the new (or modified) tooltip. */
    $tooltip.queue(function() {
        $(this)
            .stop()
            .fadeIn(global.animationSpeed);
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
};

$.fn.hideTooltip = function() {
    var
        /* Get the unique reference from the element to be used to
         * get the tooltip object. */
        tooltipRef = $(this).attr('name'),

        /* Use the above reference to get the tooltip object. */
        $tooltip = $('span[data-ref="' + tooltipRef + '"]')
    ;

    /* If there is no tooltip then there is no need to proceed. */
    if(typeof $tooltip != 'object'
        || typeof $tooltip.length != 'number'
        || $tooltip.length === 0
        || !$tooltip.is(':visible'))
        return;

    /* Hide the tooltip. */
    $tooltip
        .stop()
        .fadeOut(global.animationSpeed);
}
```

The main flaw that I'm currently aware of with this (which I'll sort out tomorrow) is that the element currently requires a `name` in order for the tooltip to work.

I think I've covered all bases with the large `if` statement within the `showTooltip` function, but I'm not sure if maybe I've gone too overboard with it. Is there any way I could condense the code?

I'm certainly no JavaScript expert, so any criticism would be very welcome!

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/UPAXV/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [optimized code at work here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPAXV/9/)

CSS: removed positioning and moved it to JS to make it dynamic

```
.tooltip {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:2px 5px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

JS: in the comments

```
//protect your code inside an immediate function
//that way, you can get away with all the crazy stuff you do
//while protecting yourself from all the crazy stuff other codes do
;(function (window, document, $, undefined) {

    //for constants, I'd declare then up top so they are easily configurable
    var animationSpeed = 250  //this one's for animation speed
      , fn = {}               //this is for our methods, explained later
      , offset = 12           //the offset caused by the triangle
      , dataName = 'tooltip'  //our data name
      ;

    //our tooltip methods

    fn.show = function (html) {

        //cache frequently used values to avoid refetching
        var element = $(this)
          , tooltip
          , offset
          , visible
          , same
          ;

        //this condition will return true if there was no data found
        //thus no tooltip was created beforehand
        if (!(tooltip = element.data(dataName))) {

            //so we create one and reference it to tooltip variable
            //we won't rely on CSS for style and dynamically calculate
            //the tooltip's position upon attachment
            tooltip = $('<span class="tooltip" />')
                        .hide()
                        .insertAfter(element)
                        .css({
                          position: 'absolute',
                          left: offset.left + element.outerWidth(true) + 12,
                          top: offset.top
                        });

            //we use jQuery's data() to avoid circular references
            //http://stackoverflow.com/q/10004593/575527
            element.data(dataName, tooltip);
        }


        visible = tooltip.is(':visible');
        same = tooltip.text() === html;

        //beware of single-line if statements. althout it looks cleaner
        //but never forget the semicolon or you'll run into problems

        //visible     same     - do nothing
        //visible     not same - fade out, change, fade in
        //not visible not same - change, fade in
        //not visible same     - fade in

        if (visible && same) return;
        if (visible) tooltip.fadeOut(animationSpeed);
        if (!same) {
          tooltip.queue(function () {
            $(this).text(html).dequeue();
          });
        }

        tooltip.queue(function () {
          $(this).stop().fadeIn(animationSpeed).dequeue();
        });

    }

    fn.hide = function () {
        var tooltip;
        //so we check if there is an existing tooltip 
        //and if that existing tooltip is visible
        if ((tooltip = $(this).data(dataName)) && tooltip.is(':visible')) tooltip.fadeOut(animationSpeed);
    }

    //now I have reformatted the tooltip to only use one name to avoid
    //possible collisions with other plugins from other developers
    //so calling targets.tooltip('show',arg1,arg2,...,argN) is the same as
    //target.show(arg1,arg2,...,argN) for each element in the set
    $.fn.tooltip = function (event) {

            //get the selected method to run
        var toExecute = fn[event],
            //remove the first argument since it only determines the method to use
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

        //check if the method exists, return if non-existent
        if (typeof toExecute !== 'function') return;

        //run the method for each of the elements in the set
        $(this).each(function () {
            toExecute.apply(this, args);
        });
    }

}(this, document, jQuery));

//usage
$(function () {
    $('button#btShow').on('click', function () {
        $('input').tooltip('show', Math.random());
    });
    $('button#btHide').on('click', function () {
        $('input').tooltip('hide');
    })
});
```

Comment: I had hard-coded the CSS for flexibility (not necessarily forcing the tooltip to display in a certain way). I'll take the `.data()` suggestion on board, I wasn't aware of any circular reference problem. Could you explain what the the top bit is doing (`;(function (window, document, $, undefined)`)? The only issue with this is that the tooltip doesn't redisplay itself when you click Show more than once - I probably should have made that a bit clearer before though! Thanks!

Comment: That bit is part of the [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), used to create an enclosed scope for your script. Call it your "private scope". Basically it's function expression that's immediately called, invoked at the bottom with `(this, document, jQuery)` as `window`, `document` and `jQuery` respectively.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Updated the script. Now it redisplays the tooltip when show is triggered more than once.

Comment: Ah awesome! Is there a reason for the "undefined" in `;(function (window, document, $, undefined) { ...`? Also, would I add more functions to this particular wrapper or would I have separate `(function (...` wrappers for each? Also, is there supposed to be a `;` at the start?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly because `undefined` is like a variable in JS, and not a constant. It's value can be changed. Thus, we create a true `undefined` in our scope by passing nothing as the 4th argument, making it truly undefined. The `;` at the beginning is to guard the our scope, especially when a function comes before it which makes JS think the starting `(` invokes it. To add functionality, just add to the `fn` collection.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot for the words of wisdom!